# Codeigniter using three queries in one functions

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, join

i have three tables

Users :

- id
- username
- password

Second table

Friends

- id
- myid
- friends_id

and last one

CI_Sessions

- session_id
- User_id = default =0
- User_data

i want Codeignier Query

```
select * from users where userid=$userid 
select * from friends where myid=$userid or friend_id=$userid
select * from ci_sessions where user_id=$userid and user_data!=''
```

return result()

is possible to get all three in one statement ?

i was trying like this

```
function check_friends($username) {
    $this->db->where('username',$username);
    $q1 = $this->db->get('users');
    $myid=$q1->row('userid');
    if($username !='' ){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');// I use aliasing make joins easier
        $this->db->where('userid',$myid);
        $this->db->join('myfriends AS friends_tpl', 'friends_tpl.myid = '.$myid.' or friends_tpl.fid='.$myid.'', 'FULL');
        $this->db->join('ci_sessions AS B', 'B.id_unite = A.userid', 'INNER');
        $this->db->where('B.user_data !=','');
        $this->db->where('B.id_unite !=','0');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }else{

    }
}
```

Update

i try this query

```
$query = $this->db->query("select * from users as u inner join myfriends as f on f.fid = '".$this->session->userdata('userid')."' or f.myid= '".$this->session->userdata('userid')."' inner join ci_sessions as c on c.id_unite = u.userid where u.username != '$username' GROUP BY u.userid ");
```

but there is problem , this query not correct result as i want ,

this is friends table value

### id |  myid | friend_id

### 1  | 50    |  54

### 2  | 57    | 50

now if three  users login , the query will show that user 54 is friend with user 57 i don't know w7y

Comment: why don't you call your model three time to execute your three quries

Comment: because this function will return online friends only , if i do like what you said i will get all users not only my friends and only online

Comment: What is the problem with your joined query ?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$query = $this->db->query(  'SELECT * -----
              UNION ALL
                SELECT * -----
              UNION ALL
                SELECT *---' );
```

this will give all result...

Comment: but result will be from witch table ?